Reconstructing function from the ratio of itself with a displaced copy
Provided the function:
$$
r(\vec{x}) = \frac{g(\vec{x}+\vec{d})}{g(\vec{x})}
$$
is it possible to obtain, even if approximately,
$$
f(\vec{x}) = \frac{g(\vec{x})}{g(0)}
$$?
$\vec{x} \in R^2 $ and $g(\vec{x})$ is smooth, positive and has no zeros in the domain of interest. However, $\vec{d}$ is not small.
Although my main interest lies in the question above, I would also be interested in a solution to the simpler case when $\vec{d}$ is small. In this case I believe I have (approximately) the the derivative of $\log({g(\vec{x}}))$ and in that case I suppose there is some integral that can be done to to obtain $g$ but I would appreciate if somebody could supply further details.
Finally, in reality g is an experimentally measured quantity so my alternative approach is to assume a parametric form for $g$ (a paraboloid) and just do a least squares fit. If I assume a parametric form is there some other way to go about it?
